# Multi-column issues on LaTeX

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to render a two column document, and for some reason neither giving `documentclass` the `twocolumn` argument nor `\begin{multicol}{2}` is working on `texlive-core` on Linux. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicol}{2}
trsgfgfdsafsdggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg ;
\end{multicol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... No need to use `\begin{multicol}{2}...\end{multicol}`, `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` is enough, please place more text and then test...

Comment: Your description, "... neither ... nor ... is working", is not exactly specific. *What*, please, isn't working?

Comment: I've changed the "align" tag to "horizontal alignment".  `align` applies explicitly to a specific math environment that is not relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors in your MWE:

1. You have to load the package [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) to use the environment `multicols`.
2. You have a typo in the environment declaration. Right syntax is `\begin{multicols}`, not `\begin{multicol}`.
3. You cannot use LaTeX’s `twocolumns` mode together with [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol), see the error message you get when compiling.
4. The long non-word you use does not hyphenate, so it is impossible for LaTeX to break the line.
5. A text of two lines will not give a proper multicolumn, so I use [lipsum](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) to create some text.

If you prefer the `twocolumn` mode instead of the package [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol), uncomment that option in my MWE, and comment out the `multicols` environment, as I have done in *Example 2*.

**Example 1 - multicol**

Here is a working MWE, using [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) and [lipsum](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum):

[image]

```
\documentclass
        %[twocolumn]
                 {article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

**Example 2 - twocolumn**

Here is a working MWE, using `twocolumn` and [lipsum](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum):

[image]

```
\documentclass
        [twocolumn]
                 {article}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
%\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know any reason why the answer you posted might not result in two columns? I'm trying to compile from the command line, it defaults to a single column even with the suggested changes. Are there any arguments I might need or a specific PDF converter than supports two column? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I discovered the issue, thank you very much for your detailed assistance!

Comment: @Silence Sorry for the silence, but I have been away from the computer for some hours. If my answer was to help, please consider to accept it. Since you are using pandoc, you may have to modify the template pandoc uses for compiling PDF. It is also possible to pass LaTeX commands from within the markup.file